# TeXLive version mismatch with remote repo when trying to install latest version

Tags: texlive, texlive-2019

My goal is to install the latest version of TeX Live, after having uninstalled the previous one, because I got the error `tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2018 < 2019)` and I couldn't install any packages.

I am following the steps at https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html, downloaded the latest installer and now I am trying to execute `./install-tl -scheme=basic`. But it fails with

```
=============================================================================
./install-tl: The TeX Live versions of the local installation
and the repository being accessed are not compatible:
      local: 2019
 repository: 2018
Perhaps you need to use a different CTAN mirror?
(For more, see the output of install-tl --help, especially the
 -repository option.  Online via https://tug.org/texlive/doc.)
=============================================================================
```

I do want to use 2019, so I figured I need to specify a repository which has TeX Live 2019.

**Question** How to do I find a repository for this specific TeX Live version (2019)?

I looked at the `-repository` documentation at https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/install-tl.html, but no help there.
I visited http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet, but specifying the repository that it linked me to, so in my case `./install-tl -scheme=basic -repository http://ctan.triasinformatica.nl/systems/texlive/tlnet/` gave the same error.

I also found in  this list of mirrors https://ctan.org/mirrors but I tried a few and they were all old.

But I'm sure there must be an updated mirror somewhere, if it's not intended that I install packages for the old TeX Live, right? (I am aware that it is *possible* to install packages for the old TeX Live, but the output message specifically redirects to a webpage which recommends updating TeX Live).

Of course I could just wait until repositories are updated, but I prefer to install TeX Live relatively soon.

Comment: Give it a few more days for the mirrors to come back into line. That particular mirror you point to, clearly haven't been updated since february/

Comment: @daleif Thanks I had downloaded the latest installer, and yeah I noticed the mirror was old. Okay I can wait, but then I wonder why they tell me to update when the mirrors are still not updated.

Comment: I think that Dante mirror is up to date.

Comment: At least it seems the Danish mirror is up to date

Comment: @Sigur That is correct, thanks! I ran `./install-tl -scheme=basic -repository ftp://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/` and it succeeded. Although it's magic to me how you found it. I guess it makes sense to look for German mirrors...

Comment: @PHPirate, if I'm not wrong, Dante is not the mirror, it is the real object... lol others are mirrors of it. Everything happens first there.

Comment: It is written *Master Host* [here](https://ctan.org/mirrors).

Comment: @Sigur Oh lol if that's the case, if you can find a source of that statement maybe you want to add an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Ah yeah it's also listed as 'root' at the bottom at https://ctan.org/mirrors/mirmon#Root

Comment: @PHPirate, please, feel free to answer yourself, no problem. Since you have the code use.

Comment: Download the .iso file from here. Pretty straight forward from there. http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/systems/texlive/Images/texlive2019.iso

Comment: @Al_Fh Thanks, though as was in the question I want to install the basic scheme, and the iso is very large so I suspect it has a larger scheme in it. But I should have made that more explicit. [Edit: I will add it to my answer for those people who want to install the full scheme]

Comment: @Al_Fh Although now I mention it, if you have a full scheme installed you won't need to install any packages so you won't have this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were too early updating TeX Live. You should at least wait a week after the release day mentioned at https://www.tug.org/texlive/ before trying any update.

If you want to install packages in the meantime, you can do the following:

1. Find a nearby mirror by visiting http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet and checking the link to which you are redirected. Copy that link.
2. You can now try installing texlive using this repository, as in the question, but probably this will fail (as this redirection is used by default).
3. Set it as default package repository, so do something like `tlmgr option repository http://some mirror site.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/` but of course for your own link.
4. When that mirror updates, this may break your installation of packages again. But hooray: now that the mirror is updated, you can finally update your TeX Live using this same mirror:

`./install-tl -scheme=basic -repository http://some mirror site.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/`

Note that you can also install a full scheme by downloading the iso file, as [@Al_Fh](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/169125/al-fh) mentions, more info at https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-iso.html

If you *really* need TeX Live 2019 *now*, look at the list of mirrors at https://ctan.org/mirrors/mirmon and try a few recent ones in your country. Click on the mirror name, and find a directory like `systems/texlive/tlnet`. If you found it, copy the url and use it in the installation command like above.

If that also doesn't work and you are really desparate, as a **last resort** try specifying the Dante repository which is the Master Host (Root) repository: this is the one from which all the others are mirrors. It is mentioned as Master Host at https://ctan.org/mirrors (thanks to [@Sigur](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14757/sigur)) and also at https://ctan.org/mirrors/mirmon#Root

Change your command to:

```
./install-tl -scheme=basic -repository ftp://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/
```

**Important** When you installed using a different package repository, after a while, when package repositories are updated, you should change back to the default by executing

```
tlmgr option repository http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet
```

Comment: It is probably no a good idea to advise others to use a root site to get the data from. If everyone does this Dante runs out of bandwidth. This is why we have the mirrors. But one should give it at least a week after release before you start using it. Also not that I don't think they have opened up for updates yet.

Comment: That's true, that should be added to this answer even though I tried that already. Will edit soon (or anyone else could edit)

Comment: @daleif updated answer, is this more like intended user behaviour?

Comment: @KJO Updated answer, I hope it's better now